# How to add a filter (like image rename) to a Theme Customization API setting

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to add several image upload fields to my theme options by using the WP Customization API.

For each of these upload fields I want to rename the uploaded file to a fixed name.

So for example, I want to add a hero_image field, and it should always be stored as hero.jpg.

I added a setting called hero_image,

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'hero_image' , array(
        'default' => '',
    ) );
```

This is the related control

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'hero_image_control',
        array(
            'label'      => 'Site hero',
            'section'    => 'context_settings',
            'settings'   => 'hero_image',
            'context'    => 'your_setting_context'
        )
    )
);
```

I know I can add a sanitize callback, but this won't rename the uploaded file.

If anyone knows how to add a preupload filter for a specific field, it would make my day :D

Comment: The only way I know of uploading images with the upload box is with Jquery. You will probably need to get the url in jquery and then rename it in php.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the rename? I currently have the upload field. I'm just wondering how to rename the file before the actual upload starts..

Comment: That might be a tricky one to execute. See this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/how-to-use-media-upload-on-theme-option-page that is how the media uploader is called, with jquery.